# regexp after a word appear

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

Im using regexp to find the text after a word appear.

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29a20/3)

The problem is some address use different abreviations for big house: Some have space some have dot

- Quinta
- QTA
- Qta.

I want all the text after any of those appear. Ignoring Case.

I try this one but not sure how include multiple start

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR ("Address",  '[^QUINTA]+') "REGEXPR_SUBSTR"
  FROM Address;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution:

I believe this will match the abbreviations you want:

```sql
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE("Address",  '^.*Q(UIN)?TA\.? *|^.*', '', 1, 1, 'i') 
    "REGEXPR_SUBSTR"
  FROM Address;
```

[Demo in SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29a20/19/0)

---

#### Explanation:

It tries to match everything from the begging of the string:

- until it finds `Q` **+** `UIN` (optional) **+** `TA` **+** `.` (optional) **+** any number of spaces.
- if it doesn't find it, then it matches the whole string with `^.*`.
- Since I'm using [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm), it replaces the match with an empty string, thus removing all characters until "`QTA`", any of its alternations, or the whole string.

Notice the last parameter passed to [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm): `'i'`. That is a flag that sets a case-**i**nsensitive match ([flags described here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm#SQLRF51666)).

The part you were interested in making optional uses a `( pattern )` that is a group with the `?` quantifier ([which makes it optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)). Therefore, `Q(UIN)?TA` matches either "`QUINTA`" or "`QTA`".

Alternatively, in the scope of your question, if you wanted different options, you need to use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) with a `|`. For example `(pattern1|pattern2|etc)` matches any one of the 3 options.  Also, the regex `(QUINTA|QTA)` matches *exactly* the same as `Q(UIN)?TA`

---

#### What was wrong with your pattern:

The construct you were trying (`[^QUINTA]+`) uses a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), and it matches **any character except** `Q`, `U`, `I`, `N`, `T` or `A`, repeated 1 or more times. But it's applied to *characters*, not *words*. For example, `[^QUINTA]+` matches the string "`BCDEFGHJKLMOPRSVWXYZ`" completely, and it fails to match "`TIA`".

Comment: What part add the `ignore case`  functionality?

Comment: Good catch. I forgot to comment on that, it's now included in the update. It's passed as `'i'` in the **`match_parameters`** in [`REGEXP_REPLACE( source_char, pattern, replace_string, position, occurrence, match_parameters)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm) described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm#SQLRF51666)

Comment: Very complete answer, Greeting from Venezuela.

Comment: Nice explanation!  I would call the alias "REGEXP_REPLACE" though :-)

Comment: I thought about it, but I wanted to keep consistency with the names used in the question.